# Azure AD and Graph

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 Web app using Azure AD, getting a token using Open ID, and trying to use that token to access the Graph.  When a user signs in, they get the following message:

[image]

From within Azure, I cannot grant the application permissions, there is no way to do that

[image]

The app is registered with apps.dev.microsoft.com.

[image]

I'm just trying to read the group memberships of the user.  How do I assign all permissions to every user in Azure Ad?  My account works when I sign in.  Others can sign in but cannot get the first prompt.  Others sign in and get redirected to sign in with another account when they try to access a page that contains this code:

```
   var baseServiceUri = new Uri(AuthConstants.ResourceUrl);
        var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(baseServiceUri, AuthConstants.TenantId), async () => await AcquireTokenAsync());
        return activeDirectoryClient;
```

Comment: Try going through authentication as an admin with `prompt=admin_consent` in the URL.

Comment: I tried this at the end of the https://login.microsoftonline.com URL and the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications registered with apps.dev.microsoft.com are known as V2 applications. You can learn more about V2 applications [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview).

As compared to V1 applications, you cannot just add `prompt=admin_consent` to trigger the admin consent flow. Instead you need to hit a special Admin Consent Endpoint.

See here: [Requesting consent for an entire tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant)

and here: [Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint)

In summary, you need to send your normal login request to this endpoint
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent` and include the normal query strings you would normally pass. Of course the user going through this flow must be a tenant administrator for the users who are struggling to sign in.

Comment: This worked.  I used the sample code in my app and it seems all users can access it.  Thanks!